# passing and setting variables in a heredoc

Tags: shell-script, here-document

I have a script that has to do many different things on many different remote machines.  I thought that a heredoc would work for this, but I am not able to use a variable defined elsewhere in the script *and* one defined in the heredoc.

Here is some code:

```
#!/bin/sh

FOO="foo"
ssh some.remote.host << EOF
  BAR="bar"
  echo "FOO=$FOO"
  echo "BAR=$BAR"
EOF
```

This only prints the following:

> FOO=
>
> BAR=bar

If, however, I quote the EOF line like this:
`ssh some.remote.host << "EOF"`
then it only prints the following:

> FOO=foo
>
> BAR=

Any hints on how I can use *both* variables inside the heredoc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In short, use:

- unquoted heredoc keywords, e.g., `EOF`
- regular dollar char for **outer** (i.e. **local**) variables, e.g., `$FOO`
- *escaped* dollar char for **inner** (i.e. **remote**) variables, e.g. `\$BAR`

---

If you leave the heredoc keyword (i.e. `EOF`) unquoted then the heredoc body is processed locally, so that `$FOO` is expanded to `foo` and `BAR` is expanded to the empty string. Then your `ssh` command becomes:

```bsh
BAR="bar"
echo "FOO=foo"
echo "BAR="
```

If you quote the heredoc keyword then variable expansion is suppressed, so that your `ssh` command becomes this instead:

```bsh
BAR="bar"
echo "FOO=$FOO"
echo "BAR=$BAR"
```

Since `FOO` is probably not defined in the remote shell environment, the expression `"FOO=$FOO"` is evaluated as `"FOO=''"`, i.e. `FOO` is set to the empty string.

If you want to use both variables then you'll need to leave the heredoc keyword unquoted, so that variable expansion takes place for the locally defined variable, and then escape (with a backslash) the variable that you want to be expanded remotely, i.e.:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

FOO="foo"
ssh some.remote.host << EOF
  BAR="bar"
  echo "FOO=$FOO"
  echo "BAR=\$BAR"
EOF
```

In this case your ssh command (as received by the remote server) will be the following:

```bsh
  BAR="bar"
  echo "FOO=foo"
  echo "BAR=$BAR"
```

Comment: That is awesome!  I have spent ages trying to figure this out.  Thank you very much for this solution.