# Can't use variables while feeding commands to bash through stdin

Tags: bash, shell, dash

I need to run a small shell script using C popen call (which calls `sh -c '<command>'`). I can't get my script to work. I isolated the issue to this snippet:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sh -c 'bash -xev -s << EOF
a=1
echo "a=$a"
EOF'
```

which outputs

```
a=1
+ a=1
echo "a="
+ echo a=
a=
```

What am I missing? Why can't I use variables from stdin?

(versions: GNU bash 5.1.4, dash 0.5.11+git20200708+dd9ef66-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body of the here-document will be subject to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion unless you quote or escape some part of the `EOF`:

```
$ sh -c 'bash -xev -s << \EOF
a=1
echo "a=$a"
EOF'
a=1
+ a=1
echo "a=$a"
+ echo a=1
a=1
```

You can also use regular quotes `"EOF"` or `'EOF'`.

For more complex cases, for example where you want some but not all variables to be expanded by the outer shell, you can leave the `EOF` unquoted and escape specific variables like `\$a` - see for example

- [passing and setting variables in a heredoc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405250/passing-and-setting-variables-in-a-heredoc)

Comment: I didn't know about `\EOF`. Thank you very much. Will mark this answer.

Comment: @ofo you can also use regular quotes `"EOF"` or `'EOF'`