# Bash script for sqlite commands

Tags: shell-script, sqlite

I wish to run a bash script that asks for a variable to be then used in a sqlite query.

I have no real experience in scripting, anyway I've tried something like the following but it doesn't work. Doesn't even give an error, just it doesn't show anything.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo name   
read name   
sqlite3 /arch.db << 'EOF'
.headers on
select type, number, address from documents where name = '$name';
EOF
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your query is looking to match against the literal five characters `$name`, not against the variable with the same name

Comment: This answer will help, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423446/100397, if not as a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing and setting variables in a heredoc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405250/passing-and-setting-variables-in-a-heredoc)

Comment: I've tried       $name
${name}
"$name"
"${name}" but none of them works....

Comment: @M.I. the quotes around `'EOF'` prevent expansion of the heredoc contents, regardless of any quoting used within it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Comment: Thanks a lot steeldriver, your suggestion helped me.

Comment: The duplicate is not exactly the same question, but it has exactly the same issue, namely the quoting of a here-document that shouldn't be quoted.

Answer (score -1):

Before answering about your script:
are you sure that the path is correct? This path: `sqlite3 /arch.db` means that `arch.db` is searched in the root `/`.

Perhaps you meant `./arch.db`? So that the sqlite db file is looked in the same path of the script?

Please note that **the `$name` var is quoted in two `'`, that means that the variable is not treated as such, but as a string.

Your script could be rewritten in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo name   
read name   
sqlite3 ./arch.db <<EOF
.headers on
select type, number, address from documents where name = "$name";
EOF
```

Comment: The `<<'EOF'` correctly introduces a quoted here-document.  There is nothing wrong with the quoting of `EOF` at the start of the here-document, other than the fact that it stops `$name` from being expanded.  The single quotes around `$name` inside the here-document is just text, not shell syntax, so they have no meaning to the shell.  Note that there is a huge difference between using single and double quotes in an SQL statement and that `"something"` refers to a column in a table, whereas `'something'` is a string.